# show specific number of posts on front page for mobile d7

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to show only a few posts for mobile I have mobile_detect as well as mobile_detect_ctools mobile_detect_variables, installed and working.

I am using an adaptive theme, `$is_mobile` successfully in theme/page.tpl but I am unable to use it in settings.php where I believe I need to set.

`$conf['default_nodes_main'] = $mobile-frontpage-post-number //(much lower than desktop);`

How can I put global `$conf` vars in page.tpl or get `$is_mobile` from mobile_detect_variables working in settings.php.

tyvm.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just redirecting the mobile devices to mobile front page(view), 
I was trying to avoid this, but it does not seem to be much trouble.

Add this code near the top of MYTHEME/page.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($is_mobile == TRUE && drupal_is_front_page()): 
drupal_goto('/mobile');
endif;
?>
```

Then you can adjust the pager, number of posts etc. I suppose this 
is a workaround not an answer.